# Rails 3 console always starts in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, environment

My rails 3 app always is stuck in the Test environment.  When I call

```
rake db:reset
```

it resets the test database, but not the development one.

When I run the following code, it loads the test environment in the console:

```
rails c
```

Trying to specify the development environment also does not work:

```
jon@jon-laptop:~/id$ RAILS_ENV=development rails console
Loading test environment (Rails 3.0.8)
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :001 >
```

Starting the server does work normally:

```
rails s
```

This is very annoying.  Any ideas on where I should look to resolve this?

Thanks in advance,

## EDIT

I also tried going back in history to earlier commit to before the problem existed (I think) and it does not fix the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.  I had the following lines in one of my initializers:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000" if Rails.env == "development"
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000" if Rails.env = "test"
```

Can you spot the mistake???

Comment: A good reason to use `Rails.env.development?` and `Rails.env.test?`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to set the environment is probably by using the RAILS_ENV environment variable, e.g.:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails console
```

**Edit**: Which version of Rails are you using? This works fine for me on 3.0.7:

```
rails c [environment]
```

E.g.

```
rails c development
```

Comment: I am using 3.0.8.  Please see my edit in the original question regarding your suggestion.